# Initializing Python static class attributes in the constructor call

Tags: python, constructor, static-members, protorpc

In some Google [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/protorpc/) there is the following code (abbreviated for clarity). The class `Note` is defined and then instantiated with a parameter in the constructor call. I wasn't aware that attributes could be initialized this way. Is this a native Python feature or some magic that is happening in the Message superclass?

```
from protorpc import messages

class Note(messages.Message):

    text = messages.StringField(1, required=True)

# Import the standard time Python library to handle the timestamp.

note_instance = Note(text = u'Hello guestbook!')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you're thinking. The class `Note` inherits from `Message`. `Message` (or some other class it inherits from) has code in its `__init__()` method to do this. There's no magic.

Comment: `Message` might have a `text` member itself. Or it might have code that takes all the keyword arguments passed to its constructor and sets them as attributes on the instance. Probably the former (a `Note` is-a `Message` after all, and it makes sense for a `Message` to have text) but you could look at the source code and see.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Almost certainly the latter, as `text` is arbitrary user-land stuff.

Comment: I still find library boilerplate to be intimidating.

Comment: Found the library code in Message.__init__: `for name, value in kwargs.items(): setattr(self, name, value)`

Comment: Interesting! Wouldn't have thunk it.